# PowerShell5.1が実行できる彩りのGHCi出力

Tags: powershell, haskell

少し前にこの[コード](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rhysd/ghci-color/master/ghci-color)を発見しましたが、ウィンドウズのPowerShell 5.1 を利用しているため、このコードを実行できませんでした。そこで、このコードの`.ps1`バージョンを作ることにして、 `sed` の代わりに `-replace` 演算子使ったものがこちらになります。

```
#!/usr/bin/env powershell

Write-Output "$([char]0x1b)[91m ---$([char]0x1b)[1;35m ghci-colour$([char]0x1b)[91m cannot print infinite sequences ---$([char]0x1b)[0m"

$GREEN = "$([char]0x1b)[92m"
$RED = "$([char]0x1b)[91m"
$CYAN = "$([char]0x1b)[96m"
$BLUE = "$([char]0x1b)[94m" 
$YELLOW = "$([char]0x1b)[93m" 
$PURPLE = "$([char]0x1b)[95m" 
$RESET = "$([char]0x1b)[0m"

$load_failed = '^Failed, modules loaded:'
$load_done = 'done'
$double_colon = '::'
$right_arrow = '\->'
$right_arrow2 = '=>'
$calc_operators = '[+-/*]'
$char = "'\\?.'"
$string = '"[^"]*"'
$parenthesis = '[{}()]'
$left_bracket = '\[(.*?)\]'
$right_bracket = '\]'
$no_instance = '^\s*No instance'
$interactive = '^<[^>]*>'

Invoke-Expression (Get-Command ghci).Path @args 2>&1 | `
    % {$_ `
        -replace $load_failed, "$RED`$0$RESET" `
        -replace $load_done, "$GREEN`$0$RESET" `
        -replace $double_colon, "$PURPLE`$0$RESET" `
        -replace $right_arrow, "$PURPLE`$0$RESET" `
        -replace $right_arrow2, "$PURPLE`$0$RESET" `
        -replace $calc_operators, "$PURPLE`$0$RESET" `
        -replace $char, "$RED`$0$RESET" `
        -replace $string, "$CYAN`$0$RESET" `
        -replace $parenthesis, "$BLUE`$0$RESET" `
        -replace $left_bracket, "$BLUE`[$RESET`$1]" `
        -replace $right_bracket, "$BLUE`$0$RESET" `
        -replace $no_instance, "$RED`$0$RESET" `
        -replace $interactive, "$RED`$0$RESET" `
    }
```

下にある画像の通り、このコードの実行自体はできますが、`2>&1` を書いても何だか `stderr` の部分は表示されてないです。どなたか、なんでそうなったか教えていただけると幸いです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: これらの記事が参考になるかもしれません。[PowerShell の stderr の落とし穴](https://fujii.github.io/2019/05/13/powershell-stderr-errorrecord/) こちらの回答で v7.1までそういう変な動作をする仕様のようです。 [How can I redirect stdout and stderr without polluting PowerShell error output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66726049/9014308) その他 [The stderr stream](https://www.pwsh-live-doc.com/the-stderr-stream), [例 3: 成功、警告、およびエラーストリームをファイルに送信する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1#example-3-send-success-warning-and-error-streams-to-a-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

どうやら問題はここ：

```
Invoke-Expression (Get-Command ghci).Path @args 2>&1 | `
    % {$_ `
```

です。

もし`2>&1`を消したら以下の画像の通りに`stderr`の部分は表示されるようになると試してわかったんです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

原因は恐らくghciとPowerShellの`stdout`は違うのです。